# Is it possible to use Camera in Background or Hidden Mode in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

There are many ways we can access Camera in Windows Phone 8 / 8.1. Most of them launch specific UI for that.

Is there any way we can access camera without displaying anything related to camera in Windows Phone 8/8.1 ?

I want my camera to capture an image when my application opens.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but maybe you can move *CaptureElement* somewhere off the screen, cover it with something.

Comment: Capturing without the user knowing about it is a *Very Bad Idea* and probably not possible for the obvious privacy and security reasons. Besides, you can't just snap an unfocused picture. What are you actually trying to achieve? There is probably a different way to do it